# Need codes for RDA in RStudio

Tags: pca, rda

I am trying to figure out how to run RDA in Rstudio. I have to compare species abundance with enviromental parameters. If anyone has any inputs on this, please help.

So far I have managed to add my data into Rstudio ---

## Data for species population

species_data <- data.frame(
Month = c("July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"),
Megace = c(91, 81, 82, 69, 59, 57, 99, 131, 149, 129, 94, 92),...)

## Data for environmental parameters

environment_data <- data.frame(
Month = c("Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"),
T2M = c(25.72193548, 25.43645161, 25.797, 26.15806452, 25.912, 25.88387097, 25.96322581, 27.37964286, 28.67387097, 28.26233333, 27.16967742, 26.22766667),
Tmax = c(27.15258065, 27.19354839, 27.644, 27.96709677, 27.70733333, 28.55935484, 29.62451613, 32.06535714, 33.34967742, 31.47766667, 29.14516129, 28.148),
Tmin = c(24.65322581, 24.07451613, 24.492, 24.87354839, 24.55466667, 23.32516129, 22.77935484, 23.83821429, 25.35645161, 26.29533333, 25.76709677, 24.80533333),...)

Do I need to standardize these data? And how to proceed further on this?